# Javascript Error Message

Tags: javascript

In my shop, there are some orders without option selected(Bypassing javascript alert) on some web browser.
what's the best javascript to reponse to various web browser include IE 9.

Here is Code.

**JS**

```
     function doCart() {
        if ( document.form1.opt1 != null && document.form1.opt1.value == "" ) {
            alert("Please Select Options");
        } else if ( document.form1.opt2 != null && document.form1.opt2.value == "" ) {
            alert("Please Select Options");
        } else if ( document.form1.opt3 != null && document.form1.opt3.value == "" ) {
            alert("Please Select Options");
        } else {
            document.form1.action = "/order/cartaction.jsp";
            document.form1.submit();
        }
     }
```

**HTML**

```
      <TABLE id="detail" cellpadding=3>
        <TR>
            <TD width=110  class="atitle">Size/Color</TD>
            <TD style="LETTER-SPACING: -1px" align="left">
                <select name="opt1" class="select_detail">
                    <option>Size/Color</option>
                    <option>--------</option>
                    <option value="BLACK/34A">BLACK/34A</option>
                    <option value="BLACK/34B">BLACK/34B</option>                                    
                </select>
            </TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD class="atitle">Bottom</TD>
            <TD style="LETTER-SPACING: 1px" align="left">
                <select name="opt2" class="select_detail">
                    <option>Bottom</option>
                    <option value="Black/S">Black/S</option>
                    <option value="Almond/S">Almond/S</option>                                           
                </select>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>

    <a href="javascript:doCart();"><img src="/images/list/doCart.gif"></a>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing closing tags on your `<select>` elements ...

Comment: It's my mis-typing i have closing tag. </select>

Comment: It looks like you are writing a Javascript. Would you like to: (a) do some research? (b) do some debugging? (c) ask someone else?

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix: Change the first two `option` elements of the first `select` element and the first `option` element of the second `select` element so that they have the attribute `value=""`. E.g., `<option value="">Size/Color</option>`.

The reason is that by default, the `value` property of an `option` element has its value taken from the *content* of the `option` element. So in your case, `document.form1.opt1.value` is initially `Size/Color`.

Comment: I fixed it with insert value="" on first option name. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulCho: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried document.getElementsByName("opt3")[0].value or assign an id to the select elements and do document.getElementById("opt3").value? I truly believe this solutions should be cross-browser ones...

Comment: It's good idea. I changed the code and it worked very well in IE, Crome, Safari. Thx.